How do I connect MySQL Workbench to SQL Server with System DSN
tl;dr how can one connect Workbench to SQL Server database using Windows Authentication and/or System DSN?
Context: Win11, SQL Server 2022, SQL Server Management Studio 20.2, MySQL 8.0, and MySQL Workbench 8.0.
We have a SQL Server instance that uses Windows Authentication. SSMS connects to it fine when Trust Server Certificate is selected. I created a System DSN that connects successfully to the SQL Server and a specific database using Windows Authentication.
How can I connect from Workbench to this SQL Database? Setting
Database System to SQL Server
and
Connection to ODBC Data Source
doesn't allow me to set the DSN to the System DSN.
I keep getting prompted for a password which isn't set or used in Windows Authentication when I set Database System Connection to ODBC (native):

Following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/using-integrated-authentication?view=sql-server-ver16#using-integrated-authentication-to-connect-to--from-an-odbc-application I tried setting Trusted_Connection=yes in Additional Parameters in Advanced tab but it made no difference.
The Workbench documentation doesn't contain illustrations of using a System DSN, nor Windows Authentication.

Why do you want to connect to SQL Server with SQL Workbench?

We are migrating data from a legacy SQL Server application to a new one that uses a flavour of MySQL.

Fair enough. I know you can setup essentially what would be the equivalent of a Linked Server connection in SQL Server, in MySQL. But depending on how you're going about that with MySQL Workbench, you can't actually directly connect and browse another database system from MySQL Workbench. So it kind of depends on what you're doing exactly in Workbench currently. IMO, I'd just use an industry standard tool to do the migration, like SQL Examiner or a free alternative. Best of luck!
